# How can I find out what version of Log4J I am using?

Tags: java, log4j

As we all know, at least four or five Log4j JAR files end up being in the classpath. How can I tell which version I am using?

Answer (score 54):

I came here after learning my servers may be vulnerable to the new Log4j  exploit ([CVE-2021-44228](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228)). So I needed to know whether I had an outdated/vulnerable build of Log4j version 2 installed.

Previous answers here do not help with detecting old versions, because they are for letting already-running Java code figure out which version of Log4j that code uses, whereas I need to know if *any* Java app could be using a vulnerable version.

Here's what I did instead:

```
sudo find / -name 'log4j*'
```

This lists all Log4j related files on my (Linux) server. That showed me a few 1.x versions, which are not vulnerable to this specific CVE, and one 2.15.0 file, which already contains the fix for the CVE.

If you run this and find file or folder names that have 2.x, where x < 15, then you are likely vulnerable, and need to figure out how to update your files ASAP.

### Caution

I was warned that this is not enough of a test for my purpose because the Log4j files may be hidden inside a .jar file, which the `find` command would not discover.

### Update

Here's a public project that attempts to scan all .jar files, in order to find Log4j code inside archives as well: *[Log4-detector](https://github.com/mergebase/log4j-detector)*

Comment: To list all JAR files on your system containing the vulnerable class file (even in fat JARs), you can use:
`for f in $(find / -name '*.jar' 2>/dev/null); do echo "Checking $f..."; unzip -l "$f" | grep -F org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class; done`

Comment: Please note that Log4j v1 also can be affected: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17571

Comment: Log4j 1.x has other vulnerabilities.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70405229/1329426 .

Comment: @Delthas Are you sure that looking for the presence of JndiLookup.class is a correct check? Newer (fixed) versions of log4j2 still include that file, albeit with the bug removed

Comment: @golimar Indeed, files that were fixed will be listed as well. The command I posted will help you find JARs that are potentially vulnerable but won't tell you if they use the patched version of Log4j or a vulnerable one.

Answer (score 18):

It depends on the ClassLoader, but have a look at [the example](http://web.archive.org/web/20170719224807/https://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/UsefulCode):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Layout;

public class X {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Package p = Layout.class.getPackage();
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println("Implementation title:   " + p.getImplementationTitle());
        System.out.println("Implementation vendor:  " + p.getImplementationVendor());
        System.out.println("Implementation version: " + p.getImplementationVersion());
    }
}
```

You can call the method `getImplementationVersion` on the `Layout` class of log4j:

```
org.apache.log4j.Layout.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

Comment: Great answer and maybe correct, but I get all nulls for that class.  The documentation provided by you says it works with 1.2 and 1.3.  That might mean that I am using version 2.

Comment: I downloaded a more recent version of Log4j ([2.13.1](https://downloads.apache.org/logging/log4j/2.13.1/)) & found that the `getImplementationVersion` & `getSpecificationVersion` methods do work with it. For older versions, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61297626/4677917).

Comment: The link given in the answer is broken. Can somebody share the example code to print the log4j version programmatically?.

Answer (score 13):

I wouldn't expect this to be the preferred method, but it is how I determined the version of Log4j that my software was using:

Open, or extract the contents of, the Log4j .jar using a .zip archiving utility ([Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer) supports this). Navigate into the "*META-INF*" sub-directory and open the file "*MANIFEST.MF*" in a text editor. Find the line starting with "*Implementation-Version*", this is the Log4j version.

Obviously, this is not a programmatic solution. But if you simply want to know what version you are using and you have the .jar archive, it works.

I noticed that `Package.getSpecificationVersion()` and `Package.getImplementationVersion()`, as mentioned in [Loic M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438968/4677917), work for other .jar libraries, but not my Log4j. It's possible that the version I am using just doesn't support it.

I downloaded version [2.13.1](https://downloads.apache.org/logging/log4j/2.13.1/) to try out the above mentioned methods and found that they do work with it. So it was my version (1.2.16) that didn't support them and returned `null`.

Answer (score 6):

To know the Log4j version during **runtime in Java**:

```java
LOGGER.info("Log4j version: " + org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());
```

Or

```java
System.out.println("Log4j version: " + org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());
```

Comment: This will usually work but it can fail in, for example, this case: one of the JARs added to my project is Apache Tika (tika-app-2.3.0.jar) which includes log4j 2.17 (as unpacked .class files, not in a JAR). This line will output 2.3.0 and not 2.17

Answer (score 5):

Delete all the JAR files of the versions you don't need (one should be enough) and to find out the version of the one that’s left, look at the filename.

For example:

```
log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

Answer (score 5):

I've written a small Bash script to check versions of each Log4j JAR file located on that server. It reads the version information from the manifest file, since trusting in file names is a little risky.

```
locs=( $(sudo find / -name 'log4j*'|grep jar) )
fcount=${#locs[@]}

echo "Found $fcount jar files"
echo " "

for (( j=0; j<${fcount}; j++ ));
do
    unzip ${locs[$j]} META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    mv META-INF/MANIFEST.MF META-INF/MANIFEST$j.MF
done

echo " "
for (( j=0; j<${fcount}; j++ ));
do
    echo ${locs[$j]}
    tail -2 META-INF/MANIFEST$j.MF
done
```

Comment: Probably run http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the various problems it reports. Just looping over the `find` output as it arrives would avoid the multiple problems you have with arrays. Briefly, `sudo find / -name 'log4j*.jar' -exec sh -c '... your loop code here ...' _ {} +`

Answer (score 5):

1. Because there are multiple versions of same classes from different Log4j dependencies, any of them could get loaded during runtime (given that same class name is present in different JAR files).
2. I use plugins provided by [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) to see the [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) dependency tree. Then I exclude the older ones to have only the needed Log4j version.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do this:

1. Put a debug breakpoint at log.debug()
2. Step 'into' next statement to determine the class which is called.
3. Check the JAR version of the called class.

Answer (score 3):

Look inside the core.jar -> log4j-core .zip\META-INF\maven\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\pom files shows the version

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind the Log4j 2 Security Vulnerability CVE-2021-45105:
On Linux and macOS you can use [Syft](https://github.com/anchore/syft) to generate a software bill of materials (SBOM) and [Grype](https://github.com/anchore/grype) to scan for vulnerabilities.  Used in combination, you can find where risky versions of Log4j exist, which versions you have and get a report on the vulnerabilities.

Apache recommend ditching Log4j 1, and at least use their ['bridge'](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html), log4j-1.2-api, to call Log4j 2 from applications which contain 1.x calls.